# how to show JSON on codemirror?

Tags: angular, codemirror

currently I am using `ngx-codemirror` - a angular wrapper on the codemirror.

in the my app

html as show

```
<ngx-codemirror [(ngModel)]="data" [autoFocus]=true [options]="{lineNumbers: true,theme: 'material',mode: 'markdown'}"></ngx-codemirror>
```

ts as show

```
data='';
   json = {
        "title": "Type",
        "description": "A type of product",
        "type": "object"
  };

constructor(){
      this.data = JSON.stringify(this.json);
}
```

it shows correctly the json text in a single line, but I want to show it in a json format instead of a string within a single line.

how would I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could send in an empty whitespace character as the `space` parameter in the [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) method. Try the following

Controller

```js
data = '';
json = {
  "title": "Type",
  "description": "A type of product",
  "type": "object"
};

ngOnInit() {
  this.data = JSON.stringify(this.json, null, ' ');    // <-- string literal ' ' as `space` argument  
}
```

You could also modify the indentation space by sending a number. For eg. `JSON.stringify(this.json, null, 4)` denotes an indentation of 4 spaces.

Template

```html
<ngx-codemirror #codemirror
  [options]="codeMirrorOptions"
  [(ngModel)]="data"
  (ngModelChange)="setEditorContent($event)">
</ngx-codemirror>
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-codemirror-fpkj9a)